# Why does my program crash when using HeapAlloc and work normally whith malloc

Tags: c++

I writed a program in C++ with the following string:

```
pDataArray[i]->hWritePipes = (HANDLE*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(HANDLE)*(MAX_THREADS - 1));
```

And when I run it I'm getting the message:

> ```
> HEAP[MultyThreading1.exe]: HEAP: Free Heap block 4f5830 modified at 4f5850 after it was freed
> MultyThreading1.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
> ```

I replaced this string with

```
pDataArray[i]->hWritePipes = (HANDLE*)malloc(sizeof(HANDLE)*(MAX_THREADS - 1));
```

And it seems the program works properly.

Have you any idea what is wrong with the first version?

Regards.

All code is bellow:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

#define MAX_THREADS 3
#define BUF_SIZE 255
#define PIPE_SIZE 64

typedef struct Args
{
    char tName[56];
    HANDLE hReadPipe;
    int n;
    HANDLE* hWritePipes/*[MAX_THREADS-1]*/;
    int i;
} ARGS, *PARGS;


void ErrorHandler(LPTSTR lpszFunction);
DWORD WINAPI recieverFunction(void *arg);
DWORD WINAPI senderFunction(void *arg);
PARGS initParg(int i);


int _tmain()
{
    PARGS pDataArray[MAX_THREADS];

    DWORD   dwThreadIdArray[MAX_THREADS];
    HANDLE  hThreadArray[MAX_THREADS];

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++)
    {
        pDataArray[i] = initParg(i);

        if (i == 0){
            pDataArray[i]->hWritePipes = (HANDLE*)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(HANDLE)*(MAX_THREADS - 1));

        }
        else {
            if (!CreatePipe(&pDataArray[i]->hReadPipe, &pDataArray[0]->hWritePipes[i - 1], NULL, NULL)){
                ErrorHandler(TEXT("CreateThread"));
                ExitProcess(3);
            }
        }


        if (pDataArray[i] == NULL)
            ExitProcess(2);

        hThreadArray[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, i==0 ? senderFunction : recieverFunction, pDataArray[i], 0, &dwThreadIdArray[i]);

        if (hThreadArray[i] == NULL)
        {
            ErrorHandler(TEXT("CreateThread"));
            ExitProcess(3);
        }
    }

    WaitForMultipleObjects(MAX_THREADS, hThreadArray, TRUE, INFINITE);

    for (int i = 0; i<MAX_THREADS; i++)
    {
        CloseHandle(hThreadArray[i]);
        if (pDataArray[i] != NULL)
        {
                HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pDataArray[i]);
                pDataArray[i] = NULL;    // Ensure address is not reused.
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

PARGS initParg(int i){
    PARGS ret = (PARGS)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(PARGS));
    ret->i = i;
    return ret;
}

DWORD  WINAPI senderFunction(void *arg) {
    string input;
    while (true) {
    }
    return NULL;
}

DWORD WINAPI recieverFunction(void *arg) {

    while (true) {}

    return NULL;
}




void ErrorHandler(LPTSTR lpszFunction)
{
    // Retrieve the system error message for the last-error code.

    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL);

    // Display the error message.

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT,
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR));
    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf,
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"),
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf);
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);

    // Free error-handling buffer allocations.

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're corrupting the heap. Application Verifier might be able to help find where it's happening.

Comment: what does sizeof(PARGS) return?

Comment: This is not the program that is having problems. The threads never terminate, so the WaitForMultipleObjects will never return, so you never reach the troublesome HeapFree

Comment: sizeof(PARGS) returns 4

Comment: @RaymonChen, I double checked it is exatly the code with the problems. It crashes before  calling of HeapFree.

Comment: @user3046085: in the code you have shown, the **only** way that `HeapFree()` can be reached is if `WaitForMultipleObjects()` fails. Otherwise, it never exits because the threads never terminate (infinite loops), thus never signal the thread handles you are waiting on. That is what Raymond tried to point out to you. Plus, you are never using or freeing `hWritePipes`, so it doesn't matter how you are allocating it.  This cannot be your real code.

Comment: I think Eric is hinting that your `HeapAlloc` call in your `initParg` function is wrong. You are allocating space for a pointer, but using the result as if you allocated enough room for the whole structure. The out-of-bounds access is corrupting the heap.

Comment: @AndrewMedico Ah, because the problem wasn't in `HeapFree` at all. The OP didn't provide a stack trace, so I had to guess.

Comment: @RemyLebeau,I understand the threads will never terminate and HeapFree() is never called. The program does nothing but it crashes. Nonetheless, I copy-pasted the code frome the question to VS and rebuilded my program and I can repeat it again: It is exactly the code that corrupts the heap. I believe, Andrew right and the problem is wrong memory allocation in initParg. But I don't understand why when I replace HeapAlloc with malloc (see my question) in main the program works normally. I allocate the same amount of memory, but when I use HeapAlloc there is heap curruption and all OK with malloc

Comment: @user3046085 HeapAlloc and `malloc` are two totally different functions.  HeapAlloc is a Windows API function, while malloc is from the compiler's library -- a compiler implements `malloc` separate and apart from HeapAlloc.  So believing that they should behave the same is a non-starter.  Second, if your program has a bug, especially a memory corruption bug, *all bets are off* as to how your program will run.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I'm sorry for being so unsmart. But malloc in windows should be implemented on top of HeapAlloc, isn't it?

Comment: @user3046085 - Maybe or maybe not.  The compiler's runtime has its own heap manager implemented.  This heap manager calls the underlying OS memory functions at various times -- this is *not* controlled by you.   The `malloc` function is the interface to the compiler's heap manager.  When you directly call `HeapAlloc`, you are bypassing the heap manager and calling the OS memory functions.  So one is a call to the compiler runtime heap manager, the other is a call to the OS.

Comment: `malloc` on Windows might also be implemented in terms of `GlobalAlloc`, making an anonymous memory mapping (`CreateViewOfFile`), or it might make its own heap(s) by calling `HeapCreate` - just to name a few other possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>(Posting an answer so it doesn't get lost in the comments)</sub>

As Eric alluded to, the `HeapAlloc` call in your `initParg` function is wrong. You are allocating enough space for a pointer (`sizeof(PARGS)`), but using the result as if you allocated enough room for the whole structure.

```
PARGS initParg(int i) {
    PARGS ret = (PARGS)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, sizeof(PARGS));
    ret->i = i;
    return ret;
}
```

You have allocated 4 bytes of memory, but the `ret->i = i` line writes to an offset ~68 bytes past the beginning of the allocated block. The out-of-bounds access is corrupting the heap.

The corrective action to take here is to allocate `sizeof(ARGS)` bytes.

As for `malloc` "fixing" the issue:

- The implementation of `malloc` you're using might internally round up allocation sizes to some larger minimum such that your illegal write happens to not corrupt anything important.
- The implementation of `malloc` you're using might space allocations far enough apart that your illegal write happens to not corrupt anything important.
- The implementation of `malloc` you're using might not perform the same sort of validation that `HeapAlloc` is doing (or might only do it on `free`) such that although your illegal write is corrupting things, it hasn't been noticed yet.

Also, note that if you switch to `malloc` for allocation, you must use `free` for de-allocation. `HeapFree` cannot be assumed to be compatible.

Comment: I just sealed. It should be sizeof(ARGS) instead of sizeof(PARGS). I was confused when malloc solved the problem and didn't notice the typo.